# Creating bigquery materialized view with dummy select

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a dummy sql query which creates a dummy table:

```
with dummy_data as (
select 1 as id, "abc" as name
union all
select 2 as id, "def" as name
)
select * from dummy_data
```

I want to create a bigquery materialized view with this data. I used following query:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW project.dataset.mytable AS (
-- above query
)
```

But I am getting error: `Materialized view query must reference at least one base table.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I must be creating view instead which is not supposed to store the data but store the query.

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW project.dataset.mytable AS (
  with dummy_data as (
    select 1 as id, "abc" as name
    union all
    select 2 as id, "def" as name
  )
  select * from dummy_data
)
```